# Topic: Load custom DSDT @ windows 7?

Tags: windows, acpi

I've extracted my BIOS DSDT, disassembled it to ASL, fixed, compiled it back to AML, and how can I make windows to load it instead of my BIOS DSDT?

Do I need to write driver or could it be done via registry or bcdedit?

On linux and freebsd that could be done easly..

Answer (score 0):

You could try Try EasyBCD.  More about all that in [this forum post](https://web.archive.org/web/20130630123352/http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/33119-Bootloader-for-custom-DSDT-aml#post566863)